# Problem with getting dropdown list from users in role admin

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, roles

Can you help me with creating `Html.DropdownList` from `ViewBag` list?
When I use following code there is an error that I can't convert list to the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

```
var allUsers = db.Users.ToList();
var adminUsers = allUsers.Where(u => u.Roles.Select(r =>r.RoleId).Contains("1bafec08-fc36-41f6-a3f1-cc9a297e7481")).ToList();

ViewBag.Role = adminUsers;
```

This way of displaying doesn't work:

```
@Html.DropDownList("PersonAssigned",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Role, "Wybierz pracownika:", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Also this doesn't:

```
@Html.DropDownList("PersonAssigned", ViewBag.Role as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a SelectList before putting it in ViewBag like:

```
ViewBag.Role = new SelectList(adminUsers,"RoleId","RoleName");
```

and in your view in the DropDownList helper use:

```
ViewBag.Role as SelectList
```

Assuming the `RoleName` is the column name in your table, otherwise you need yo put the column name you have in the table for the role text.

Answer (score 0):

Mapping to required type is missing, also consider optimization your db query

```
var roleId = Guid.Parse("1bafec08-fc36-41f6-a3f1-cc9a297e7481");
var adminUsers = db.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Any(y => y.RoleId == roleId))
    .ToList()
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem() 
    {
        Text = x.RoleName,
        Value = x.RoleId
    })
    .ToList();
```

This will enable this code to work

```
@Html.DropDownList("PersonAssigned",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Role, "Wybierz pracownika:", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll try this out ;)